# Parse: How do I override Class Level Permission with ACL?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Post class that contains user posts.  The posts should be public readable but unable to write to.  However a user(author) should be able to write/delete their own posts. Here are my permission settings on the Post class -

**Class Level Permission**: Public-Read
**Access Control Level**: Public-Read, Author(pointer)-Read/Write

I get access denied when I try to delete the post.  If CLP always overrides object ACL, what's the point of ACL at all?!!

If that's the case, should my CLP be read/write for Public then?!!  How can I get around this or do I HAVE to write Cloud Code?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLP (Class Level Permission) are overwritten by the ACL when they allow an action. If you do not enable the Update CLP, nobody will be able to update any objects on the table, even if they have the right ACL. When you enable the Update CLP for public, the ACL will control what people can update your objects.

So as long as the CPL *and* the ACL are not allowing any Update/delete for "public" you are "safe".

Comment: So let's say I have a class "Default" for all registered users.  In my Posts class, what do I implement for CLP and ACL given that only the post owner can edit it?  Is it?

CLP - Default: read (true) + write (true)
ACL - Default: read (true) + write (false), User<pointer>: read (true) + write (true)

So basically even though i have Default with both permissions, I set it to false in my ALC but I enable it for the individual user who owns the post?

Comment: By doing a lot of testing. But the CPL / ACL are a pain in this ass. If you don't get them right when you create the table it can be a nightmare (if you need to update thousands of objects to change their ACL, it might take a while because of the parse limit). So now I only use Parse Cloud to handle everything and I put all CLP to false to all my classes.

Comment: Yeah I wish they would be clear on what's the "best" practices for CPL/ACL cases.  I've been avoiding Cloud Code because I wasn't sure if I should use it to substitute for CPL but I don't see much of a way around it!